# Cannot evaluate property value inline

Tags: typescript

I cannot evaluate a property inline in a nested dictionary. If I evaluate the property into a separate local variable, it works. Why is that?

This throws an error

```
const appConfig = {
  config.networks!.testnet?.chainId! : {
    "token1": "mytoken"
  }
};
```

This works

```
const chainId = config.networks!.testnet?.chainId!;
const appConfig = {
   chainId : {
    "token1": "mytoken"
  }
};
```

Comment: Because it's just not valid syntax?

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to typescript, so please if you could help

Comment: Not sure, so how should I reference the chain id with proper syntax?

Comment: I see, so I guess I need to add it later, cannot add it during initialization

Comment: A nomenclature hint: In TypeScript/JavaScript, we call them "objects", not "dictionaries". The answers to the linked question are quite clear: Use the bracket syntax to add the property (e.g., `{ [chainId] : { token1: "mytoken" } }`).

Answer (score 1):

Because you forgot the brackets
... in **BOTH** cases

```
const appConfig = {
  [config.networks!.testnet?.chainId!] : {
    "token1": "mytoken"
  }
};
```

```
const chainId = config.networks!.testnet?.chainId!;
const appConfig = {
   [chainId] : {
    "token1": "mytoken"
  }
};
```

Typescript is not Python, `chainId` key means string `"chainId"` key

Also you can only have string (and number, and symbol) keys (everything else (including numbers) is cast to string)
If you need to use objects as keys, use `new Map<KeyType, ValueType>(pairs: [KeyType, ValueType][])`

Comment: thanks, so why is the second one not throwing error then? the one with the local variable

Comment: @siamii because it's `const appConfig = {
   "chainId" : {
    "token1": "mytoken"
  }
};` (`chainId` interpreted as literal string key) . It would still work if you delete the line with variable